# Modern SSD maximum amount of writes

Tags: ssd

Surprisingly, I couldn't find an answer to this basic question. What is the maximum amount of writes until a modern SSD wears out, and how does this number compare to the limit of older SSDs?

Comment: Look at the specs for a specific modern model?

Comment: Clearly an answer would be brand and model specific. This is the equivalent of *What are the maximum number of miles you can get in a modern car's life, and how does that number compare to older cars?*. How could you possibly answer that question definitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple single answer here as there are a large number of variables. The main ones are - type of memory/bits per cell, size of print process (bigger is better), insulation (3d cells are apparently better because of this) amount of over provisioning of memory, and firmware for management.

Older SSDs could typically do more writes, but squandered them.

A single cell can typically handle a few thousand writes - but when combined with wear leveling this is a lot more than it sounds.

SLC (single bit per cell) can handle about 10 times the writes of MLC (multiple bits per cell).

Have a look at http://www.storagesearch.com/ssdmyths-endurance.html.

You have not advised why you are asking the question, but in practice, for the vast majority of workloads you are looking at more than 5 years lifespan on a typical SSD. Be aware though that when SSDs die, they tend to do so more suddenly and catastrophically than hard drives, do regular backups/raid is a must. (On the flip side they are about 10 times as reliable as spinning disks)

Comment: Thank you for the good answer, and the article which expands on it, and has some extra valuable information. The reason I've asked the question is mostly curiosity and interest in the topic :)